# Slow loop for element replacement in list of lists

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I wrote a loop to conditionally replace elements in a list of lists. While still relatively new to R, I feel certain that I am not going about this as efficiently as possible. The following loop runs very slowly (an hour or so) on my actual data. I've included a minimal working example below that exactly replicates the structure of my data.

```
A <- matrix(c(0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0), nrow = 2, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
B <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0), nrow = 2, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
C <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), nrow = 1, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
D <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), nrow = 1, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
mList <-list(list(A, B))
dList <- list(list(C, D))
```

The goal of the loop is to replace all cells in column j of the nth item of `mList2` with `0` if element j of the nth item of `dList` equals `0`.

```
mList
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    0    1    1    2    0    0
# [2,]    1    0    1    2    0    0
#
# [[1]][[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    2    0    1
# [2,]    1    0    1    2    0    0

dList
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    0    0    1    0    1
#
# [[1]][[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
```

Is this another instance of unrealized gains from using the set of `apply` functions? Is there some better way of doing this that doesn't involve using four indices?

```
for(i in 1:length(dList)) {
    for(j in 1:length(dList[[i]])) {
        for(k in 1:length(dList[[i]][[j]])) {
            for(m in 1:nrow(mList[[i]][[j]])) {
                mList[[i]][[j]][m, k] <- 
                    ifelse(
                        dList[[i]][[j]][k] == 1, 
                        mList[[i]][[j]][m, k], 
                        0
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Resulting in:

```
mList
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    0    0    0    2    0    0
# [2,]    1    0    0    2    0    0

# [[1]][[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    0    0    0    2    0    1
# [2,]    0    0    0    2    0    0
```

Comment: I think I might know why you are having speed issues.  First though, why do you have nested lists?

Comment: Each list at the first level is a year, and each year contains many adjacency matrices. The data are organized that way so as to be able to easily access specific years and matrices. Now that I think about it I could unlist the outer list and incorporate the year into each matrix name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a nested `lapply` to loop through the nested structure of the input lists, recomputing the relevant entry in `mList` using a single vectorized operation instead of a loop through the columns and rows:

```
lapply(seq_along(dList), function(i) {
  lapply(seq_along(dList[[i]]), function(j) {
    t(t(mList[[i]][[j]]) * as.vector(dList[[i]][[j]] != 0))
  })
})
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    0    0    0    2    0    0
# [2,]    1    0    0    2    0    0
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    0    0    0    2    0    1
# [2,]    0    0    0    2    0    0
```

Here's a benchmark on a list of the same structure, with 10 x 10000 matrices in `mList`. I've benchmarked the solution you provide, the solution by @thelatemail, and my solution:

```
set.seed(144)
A <- matrix(sample(0:2, 100000, replace=TRUE), nrow=10)
B <- matrix(sample(0:2, 100000, replace=TRUE), nrow=10)
C <- matrix(sample(0:1, 10000, replace=TRUE), nrow=1)
D <- matrix(sample(0:1, 10000, replace=TRUE), nrow=1)
mList <-list(list(A, B))
dList <- list(list(C, D))

OP <- function(mList, dList) {
  for(i in 1:length(dList)) {
    for(j in 1:length(dList[[i]])) {
        for(k in 1:ncol(dList[[i]][[j]])) {
            for(m in 1:nrow(mList[[i]][[j]])) {
                mList[[i]][[j]][m, k] <- 
                    ifelse(
                        dList[[i]][[j]][k] == 1, 
                        mList[[i]][[j]][m, k], 
                        0
                    )
            }
        }
    }
  }
  mList
}
josilber <- function(mList, dList) {
  lapply(seq_along(dList), function(i) {
    lapply(seq_along(dList[[i]]), function(j) {
      t(t(mList[[i]][[j]]) * as.vector(dList[[i]][[j]] != 0))
    })
  })
}
thelatemail <- function(mList, dList) {
  Map(
    function(L,s) Map(function(sL,ss) {sL[,ss] <- 0; sL}, L, s),
    mList,
    lapply(dList, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) y==0) )
  )
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OP(mList, dList), josilber(mList, dList), thelatemail(mList, dList), times=10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                       expr          min           lq         mean       median           uq          max neval
#           OP(mList, dList) 12252.468288 13318.745019 13478.116388 13486.732412 13840.106332 14259.053497    10
#     josilber(mList, dList)     2.299442     2.401806     2.561809     2.480822     2.552620     3.511609    10
#  thelatemail(mList, dList)     4.259594     4.438562     4.683855     4.612297     5.002605     5.122605    10
```

Both solutions run more than 1000 times faster, mainly because they're not tightly looping through the matrices but instead performing the operation in a vectorized manner.

Comment: Nice benchmarks. Expressing the times in seconds really brings home the improvement: `OP:12.252s  josilber:0.002s  thelatemail:0.004s`

Comment: Thanks so much! This runs MUCH faster. I've a lot of de-looping of my code ahead of me.

Answer (score 2):

It's not pretty, but you essentially always need to double loop with a nested list structure.

```
Map(
  function(L,s) Map(function(sL,ss) {sL[,ss] <- 0; sL}, L, s),
  mList,
  lapply(dList, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) y==0) )
)
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    0    0    0    2    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    0    2    0    0
#
#[[1]][[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    0    0    0    2    0    1
#[2,]    0    0    0    2    0    0
```

I've just replaced all the `for()` loops with a nested `lapply` to generate the lists of columns to overwrite, then used a nested `Map` to replace the columns within each list.